# Change default gerrit commit-msg

Tags: gerrit

I would like to change the default Gerrit commit-msg hook to add Signed-off-by automatically. However, I cannot find the file commit-msg in Gerrit server, it seems like the commit-msg is wrappered in gerrit.war file.

Is there any way I can change the default Gerrit commit-msg hook?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. But would also need that. Could you ask that on the [repo-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/repo-discuss) list, please?

Answer (score 4):

There is another way which can help to get your own commit-msg hook instead of the default one from Gerrit.
The idea is providing another version of the hook and then ask Gerrit to prompt the Shel command to get that version for you.

Here is how you can make it.

1. Setup a file server with Nginx or Apache, and put your own `commit-msg` hook into that server. After doing this, you would get an URL of that `commit-msg` hook
2. Configure an item named `gerrit.installCommitMsgHookCommand` in Gerrit's configure file `gerrit.config` with a shell command which could download your `commit-msg` hook
3. Restart Gerrit server

For example, the value of `gerrit.installCommitMsgHookCommand` in my Gerrit server is: 

`gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); 
wget -qO ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg http://myservername/hooks/commit-msg; 
chmod a+x ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg`

When I push a commit to my Gerrit server without Change-Id line in the commit message, I will get the following prompt:

*remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done

remote: ERROR: missing Change-Id in commit message footer

remote: 

remote: Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:

remote: gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); wget -qO ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg http://myservername/hooks/commit-msg; chmod a+x ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg

remote: And then amend the commit:

remote:   git commit --amend*

By reading the description of item gerrit.installCommitMsgHookCommand in Gerrit document, you can see how it works clearly.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You need to develop your own patchset-created and draft-published hooks to use in $GERRIT_SITE/hooks. It's important to remember that these hooks need to create a new patchset (commit) to add the signed-off-by info.

Comment: Do you means the hooks installs on Gerrit? And when user push a new patchset on Gerrit, it triggers the hook to add the signed-off-by to commit message?

Comment: Exactly, when a user pushes a new patchset to Gerrit it triggers the hooks on $GERRIT_SITE/hooks directory. You need to develop a hook to edit the patchset, add the signed-off-by info and commit the new patchset. See more info here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-hooks.html

Comment: I forgot to mention: you can set "Require Signed-off-by in commit message" = TRUE in projects config to require the Signed-off-by info in every commit pushed to Gerrit. See more info here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#_require_signed_off_by

Answer (score 0):

You can find `commit-msg` in this location:

```
gerrit.war
    WEB-INF/lib/gerrit-server-server.jar
        com/google/gerrit/server/tools/root/hooks/commit-msg
```

`gerrit.war` and `WEB-INF/lib/gerrit-server-server.jar` are archive so you must unzip it and after change repack again

Answer (score 0):

Changing the commit message straight away on the server side it's a very bad idea. Consider that the SHA-1 is made also from the commit message so, say you want to add the Signed-off-by only when the change is submitted to the tree. You will end up with a different SHA-1 and the user would still have the previous SHA-1 in the commit... do you see where I am going?